# ReactJS input does not get focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's my code for the parent component (FundLogo):

```
var FundLogo = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return { editing: false, img: "img/xxx.gif" };
},
onClick: function() {
    this.setState({ editing: true });
},
onBlur: function(newImg) {
    this.setState({ editing: false, img: newImg});
},
render: function() {
    return(
        <div className="banner_holder adj_height">
            {
                this.state.editing ?
                    <FundEditLogoBox onBlur={ this.onBlur } /> :
                    <img id="fund_logo" src={ this.state.img } onClick={ this.onClick } alt="finvesco logo" />
            }
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

And here is the one for the child component (FundEditLogoBox):

```
var FundEditLogoBox = React.createClass({
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.refs.editLogoBox.getDOMNode().focus();
    alert("Focus is on: " + document.activeElement);
},
onBlur: function() {
  this.props.onBlur(this.refs.editLogoBox.getDOMNode().value);
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" onBlur={ this.onBlur } accept="image/*" ref="editLogoBox" />
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Basically what my code is supposed to do:

1. Show an image in a container
2. When the image is clicked an upload button is shown in the container instead of the image.
3. If you click outside the upload button (input), without choosing an image to upload, the previous image is shown instead of the upload button.

The problem I have is that the input (from the child component) does not get any focus when it gets mounted. I have to click on it to obtain focus. Furthermore, the alert shows

> "Focus is on: [object HTMLBodyElement]"

I looked for similar issues everywhere on the web but nothing worked, and unlike other issues it does not seems it's a "re-rendering" problem...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is something else that's missing from this picture, I tried it in a fiddle and it works as intended. http://jsfiddle.net/mncusu4f/ , what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        ref={function(input) {
          if (input != null) {
            input.focus();
          }
        }} />
    );
  },
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute

Comment: Thanks for your help François, but it doesn't seem to be the problem. Indeed, even if the method is deprecated this was returning my input element correctly. I tried with React.findDOMNode but no improvement.

Comment: Edited I think I got your problem

Comment: Sorry for the autofocus I forgot it, but it is not the problem. I still get the focus on the body...

Comment: Using TextInput I get "ReferenceError: TextInput is not defined" (in fact there is no TextInput component so it's a normal behaviour). When changing TextInput to input I get "TypeError: input.focus is not a function". So unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well read the documentation, try to understand, it perfectly fit your needs if you take time to read the documentation react provided. At this point there is nothing I can do for you except rewriting your whole page, maybe you'll find someone to do that but I have not time to do it now. However I think that with the guidance I gave you and little efforts you'll be able to get thorugh your problem. Hope it helped. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your time François. It seems it is not a ReactJS problem. In fact once the input get the focus (or get clicked) the blur event is trigger, so the input instantly lose the focus. Hope it will help others.

Comment: Also autofocus is not written right, it's autoFocus with react

Comment: I removed the autofocus since it is not the problem and might be confusing